# check boolean value again and again

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to build infinite scroll for my cards.
I am using a variable `reload` in data.service to check for need to load more data which is getting set to **true** when page end is getting reached.
The variable setting to **true is done by app.component**
The content population is done in post.component
And ```reload`` is present in ***data.service*** which is using http service to fetch for content from php server.
Curently I am using *observable* and trying to access reload status repeatedly but it is getting subscribed only once on Init.

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component,HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import * as M from 'materialize-css';
import {DataService} from './current/posts/post-card/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent
{

  title = 'cosmos';
  constructor(private scrollSet: DataService){}

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event:any) 
  {
    if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >= event.target.scrollHeight-100)
      {
        console.log("noww");
        this.scrollSet.setValue(true);
      }
  }
}
```

***post.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from './data.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-card',
  templateUrl: './post-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-card.component.css']
})
export class PostCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private data: DataService,public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,private titleService:Title) 
  { 
    this.titleService.setTitle("Current Feed | Cosmos");
  }

  received = 'none';

  posts: any = [];

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.data.getPostData().subscribe(data =>
      {
      this.posts.push(data);
      this.received='success';
      },
      error =>
      {
        this.received='error';
      });

    this.data.getValue().subscribe((value) => {
      this.data.getPostData().subscribe(data =>
      {
      this.posts.push(data);
      this.received='success';
      },
      error =>
      {
        this.received='error';
      });
    });
  }
}
```

***data.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private reload: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  { 
    this.reload = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  fetchGap=5; // use this to set number of results wanted per fetch
  fetchEnd:number= 0;


  setValue(newValue): void {
    this.reload.next(newValue);
  }
  getValue(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.reload.asObservable();
  }
  getPostData(){
    this.fetchEnd+=this.fetchGap;
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:1234/Server/getPosts.php?fetchEnd='+this.fetchEnd+'&fetchGap='+this.fetchGap);
  }
}
```

Comment: your now is priting in console at every scroll down?

Comment: yes..its printing fine

Comment: try printting value in getvalue.subscribe in post component?

Comment: thats working fine too...my actual question is how to repeatedly keep on checking on the value of ```reload```.Currently the subscribe part is only working ONCE on Init.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you haven't set the value of reload to false after your treatment.
try to check inside post.component.ts. here is a portion of that code, the block which suscribe to reload.

**post.component.ts reload block**

```
   this.data.getValue().subscribe((value) => {
      if(value){
        this.data.getPostData().subscribe(data =>
          {
            this.posts.push(data);
            this.received='success';
          },
          error =>
          {
            this.received='error';
          });
          this.data.setValue(false);
       }
   });
```